# greping for a value != *.file extension

Tags: bash, unix, grep

Not 100% on how to go about this.

Basically my app creates two file outputs.

```
file
file.ext
```

when searching through the directory it always returns both files. I wish only to work with

```
file
```

how can I do a grep for just the file? Or is grep even the correct command?

```
!grep *.ext
```

pseudo code ^

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
grep foobar file
```

or if you want to search your directory

```
find . -name 'file' | xargs -r grep boofar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using grep 'file$', i.e. select lines ending with file and nothing after that. Alternatively you can use grep -v to invert results.

```
# (echo "file"; echo "file.txt") | grep file$
file
# (echo "file"; echo "file.txt") | grep -v .ext
file
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are trying to do with grep, but if you want to check whether a file exists, you do simply this:

```
if [ -r /some/path/file ]; then
  echo "File is readable."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Grep has a `-v` flag that inverses the meaning (looks for lines that do *not* contain the pattern):

```
ls /your/directory | grep -v '\.ext$'
```

This will exclude every filename ending with `.ext`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
grep -v option
```

-v do the inverse match

For details do `$ man grep`

Answer (score 0):

To generate a list of all files that do not match a pattern, use `-not` in find.  So you want:

```
find . -not -name '*.ext'
```